# How can i make a calendar with all days in one row

Tags: javascript, calendar, typescript

```
How can i make a calendar with all days in one row
```

I have searched for this answer a lot, but still I did not find a single appropriate answer or solution to this problem ....

I am sure lot of people have done that, but it is really strange that someone still did not explain how they have done it.

Do anyone of you knows the answer, do to do this in javaScript or TypeScript !

```
How can i make a calendar with all days in one row
```

Most of the table we see in the JQuery library or some other resources they are all `7 days in 1 row table`

What I want to see 30 days in 1 rows instead of 7 days in the calendar !

example ---

[image]

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I don't actually understand the question.

Comment: @JamesHill thank you, just udated the question

Comment: So, you want to display the current month as a row of days?

Comment: @JamesHill No, just 30 days, like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... and so on ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and slow way:

```
var
   startDate = new Date( 2015, 0, 1 )
   , numOfDays = 30
   , days = []
   ;

function addDay( date ) {
   date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
}

while ( numOfDays-- ) {
   days.push( startDate.getDate() + '/' + ( startDate.getMonth() + 1 )
                                         + '/' + startDate.getFullYear() );
   addDay( startDate );
}
console.log( days.join() );
```

Result in console:

```
1/1/2015,2/1/2015,3/1/2015,4/1/2015,5/1/2015,6/1/2015,7/1/2015,8/1/2015,9/1/2015,10/1/2015,11/1/2015,12/1/2015,13/1/2015,14/1/2015,15/1/2015,16/1/2015,17/1/2015,18/1/2015,19/1/2015,20/1/2015,21/1/2015,22/1/2015,23/1/2015,24/1/2015,25/1/2015,26/1/2015,27/1/2015,28/1/2015,29/1/2015,30/1/2015
```

I used counter for 30 iterations. You can change the condition to make days within a month.
But I prefer to use Julian days because it faster way than above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer, although I was looking for a proper calendar, but I guess this is a good start :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, the fact is that you just need an array with a certain format. Let's find out how to generate this array.

First, allow me to introduce a library: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which will be used to illustrate. You can also use pure JavaScript to replace it.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var resultArray = [];

var util = {};

/** 
 * input:
 *   month [Number]
 * output:
 *   totalDays [String]
 */
util.getDaysOfMonth = function(month){
  month = +month;
  var totalDays = '31';

  if( /[469]|(11)/.test(month) ){
    totalDays = '30';
  } else if (month === 2) {
    totalDays = moment().isLeapYear() ? '29' : '28';
  }

  return totalDays;
}

// Get current month of the year
var month = moment().get('month') + 1;

// current year
var year  = moment().get('year');
var days  = util.getDaysOfMonth(month);
for(var i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
  var str = month + '/' + i + '/' + year;
  resultArray.push(str);
}
```

And now you can do the format thing with this array.